# Настроить визуальное отображение изменений (аля DreamViewer или FireBug)?

Tags: phpstorm, визуализация

Добрый день. Подскажите, никак не могу найти. Есть ли такая возможность отобразить все вносимые изменения realtime как в DreamViewer или FireBug, очень устаёшь рефрешить страницу при вёрстке.

Comment: [Live Edit](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007) уже пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Live Edit in PhpStorm`](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/live-edit-in-phpstorm/)

> Live Edit gives you an opportunity to
> see all the changes instantly in the
> browser without refreshing the page.
> Just install the browser extension,
> and as you edit HTML, CSS or
> JavaScript in PhpStorm, Live Edit will
> reload the corresponding browser pages
> and highlight the elements you are
> working on. Completion lookup is also
> live.

P.S.: ну гуглится ведь за 8 секунд...